# What does the presence of the perfect tense reveal about us?

Tags: present-perfect, philosophy

Other languages might say 'the floor is clean' or 'the cat is hungry'. An English speaker might say this, or we might equally choose to say 'the floor has been cleaned' or 'the cat hasn't been fed'. [Married couples seem to use a lot of present perfect simples!]

I was wondering whether anyone has any insights into the philosophical implications of perfect tenses - particularly what their presence within our language system reveals about the psyche or culture of English speakers.

I've been wrestling with this for some time. My initial conclusion was that this tendency to describe the world as a the result of a series of past actions suggested that we were interventionists, not fully content to just let the world 'be'. Not very Buddhist!

However, I have since questioned this evaluation, and now I am wondering whether 'the floor has been cleaned' is simply an acknowledgement of change over time, something which is less explicit, though maybe implied, with 'the floor is clean'.

Why do we have this need to present the past?

Comment: What do you do with a language that doesn't have a present tense? The reason couples use a lot of perfect is that they're keeping each other up to date about what's been happening -- one of the necessities of division of labor is that folks miss what's going on elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnLawler I imagine you can do a lot, since there are language that don't have tense!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenseless_language

Comment: OP: It seems you are asking about how language structures thinking, or the reverse.  For an intro to this complex philosophical debate, try these 3 resources: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/relativism/supplement2.html http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eskimo_words_for_snow http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3274/does-language-influence-thinking-skills-or-cognition/3280#3280

Answer (score 1):

The statements "the floor is clean" and "the floor has been cleaned" have different meanings; there is no need to bring any sort of philosophy of outlook into the picture.

"The floor is clean" means that the floor was cleaned and definitely remains clean, or was never dirty. "The floor has been cleaned" means the action of cleaning the floor is complete, but not that it is necessarily still clean. It also makes it more obvious that some agent cleaned the floor rather than that the floor just is clean.

Comment: I am aware of the difference in meaning. I was just trying to generate an interesting discussion about the cultural implications of perfect tenses. It seems this is the wrong place to do this!

Comment: This is not a discussion board.

Comment: It's obvious that the semantically encoded meaning is different... @thecrease's question seems to be about *usage*. And I'm afraid whichever way you look at is it most certainly *is* a question of 'outlook'. After all the difference between present, present perfect and past is not one of facts, just perspective. This difference and indeed this question is all about *ASPECT*.